# Подскажите пожалуста почему не работает grid

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: #b5fd8b;
  user-select: none;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="item input">
    <form name="form"><input type="text" name="textview" readonly></form>
  </div>
  <div class="item clean">C</div>
  <div class="item back">&larr;</div>
  <div class="item">+</div>
  <div class="item">-</div>
  <div class="item">&times;</div>
  <div class="item">&divide;</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">(</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">)</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item equal">=</div>
  <div class="item zero">0</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что грид не работает?

Comment: @Grundy, ну видно же.

Comment: Используй отладку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.container
     ^

class="conteiner"
           ^
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @МаксимКравченко, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это же ответ.

Comment: если бы только это было - надо было закрыть как опечатку :-) но он там еще и свойство неправильное использует

Comment: «это же ответ» — и это пишет модератор. куда катится этот мир? впрочем, если уж катиться вместе с этим миром, то, наверно, про каждую из опечаток в вопросе надо писать *отдельный* это-же-ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я ж даже вопрос закрыл.

Comment: @Grundy, ну переоткрой тогда.